# CTFT of $t \mapsto (t − 1) e^{−2t} u(t − 1)$

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-transform, signal-processing

Determine the CTFT and the corresponding energy of the signal $$x(t) = (t − 1) e^{−2t} u(t − 1)$$ For this same signal: find the even and odd parts of this signal and then determine there corresponding CTFT's.

Comment: Say that CTFT = continuous time Fourier Transform.